# Cannot start the mariadb.service in the 3rd node

Tags: mariadb, galera

I have three nodes in a mariadb cluster. Node 3 cannot start mariadb:

[image]

I use the `systemctl status mariadb.service`:

```
[root@ha-node3 log]# systemctl status mariadb.service 
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-08-06 10:32:12 CST; 4min 1s ago
  Process: 23807 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 23803 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 06 10:32:12 ha-node3 sh[23807]: InnoDB: Set innodb_force_recovery to ignore this error.
Aug 06 10:32:12 ha-node3 sh[23807]: 2017-08-06 10:32:11 139908193081536 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
Aug 06 10:32:12 ha-node3 sh[23807]: 2017-08-06 10:32:11 139908193081536 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Aug 06 10:32:12 ha-node3 sh[23807]: 2017-08-06 10:32:11 139908193081536 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Aug 06 10:32:12 ha-node3 sh[23807]: 2017-08-06 10:32:11 139908193081536 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
Aug 06 10:32:12 ha-node3 sh[23807]: 2017-08-06 10:32:11 139908193081536 [ERROR] Aborting'
Aug 06 10:32:12 ha-node3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 06 10:32:12 ha-node3 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Aug 06 10:32:12 ha-node3 systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Aug 06 10:32:12 ha-node3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
```

I use the `journalctl -xe` to check:

```
Aug 06 11:10:46 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: START: mysqlchk pid=42863 from=::ffff:192.168.8.101
Aug 06 11:10:46 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: EXIT: mysqlchk signal=13 pid=42862 duration=0(sec)
Aug 06 11:10:46 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: EXIT: mysqlchk status=1 pid=42863 duration=0(sec)
Aug 06 11:10:46 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: START: mysqlchk pid=42871 from=::ffff:192.168.8.102
Aug 06 11:10:46 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: EXIT: mysqlchk status=1 pid=42871 duration=0(sec)
Aug 06 11:10:48 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: START: mysqlchk pid=42894 from=::ffff:192.168.8.103
Aug 06 11:10:48 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: START: mysqlchk pid=42898 from=::ffff:192.168.8.101
Aug 06 11:10:48 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: EXIT: mysqlchk signal=13 pid=42894 duration=0(sec)
Aug 06 11:10:48 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: EXIT: mysqlchk status=1 pid=42898 duration=0(sec)
Aug 06 11:10:48 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: START: mysqlchk pid=42903 from=::ffff:192.168.8.102
Aug 06 11:10:48 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: EXIT: mysqlchk status=1 pid=42903 duration=0(sec)
Aug 06 11:10:50 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: START: mysqlchk pid=42914 from=::ffff:192.168.8.103
Aug 06 11:10:50 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: START: mysqlchk pid=42918 from=::ffff:192.168.8.101
Aug 06 11:10:50 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: EXIT: mysqlchk signal=13 pid=42914 duration=0(sec)
Aug 06 11:10:50 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: EXIT: mysqlchk status=1 pid=42918 duration=0(sec)
Aug 06 11:10:50 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: START: mysqlchk pid=42923 from=::ffff:192.168.8.102
Aug 06 11:10:50 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: EXIT: mysqlchk status=1 pid=42923 duration=0(sec)
Aug 06 11:10:52 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: START: mysqlchk pid=42928 from=::ffff:192.168.8.103
Aug 06 11:10:52 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: START: mysqlchk pid=42929 from=::ffff:192.168.8.101
Aug 06 11:10:52 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: EXIT: mysqlchk signal=13 pid=42928 duration=0(sec)
Aug 06 11:10:52 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: EXIT: mysqlchk status=1 pid=42929 duration=0(sec)
Aug 06 11:10:52 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: START: mysqlchk pid=42937 from=::ffff:192.168.8.102
Aug 06 11:10:52 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: EXIT: mysqlchk status=1 pid=42937 duration=0(sec)
Aug 06 11:10:54 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: START: mysqlchk pid=42944 from=::ffff:192.168.8.103
Aug 06 11:10:54 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: START: mysqlchk pid=42945 from=::ffff:192.168.8.101
Aug 06 11:10:54 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: EXIT: mysqlchk signal=13 pid=42944 duration=0(sec)
Aug 06 11:10:54 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: EXIT: mysqlchk status=1 pid=42945 duration=0(sec)
Aug 06 11:10:54 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: START: mysqlchk pid=42953 from=::ffff:192.168.8.102
Aug 06 11:10:54 ha-node3 xinetd[1199]: EXIT: mysqlchk status=1 pid=42953 duration=0(sec)
```

Comment: Did you alter the innodb_log_file_size in the my.cnf?

Comment: @DearWatson I did not, it before is `innodb_log_file_size = 2000M` , but  after the host machine reboot, the node3 can not start the mariadb now.

Answer (score 1):

The following log line indicates an issue with InnoDB:

```
Aug 06 10:32:12 ha-node3 sh[23807]: InnoDB: Set innodb_force_recovery to ignore this error.
```

Having log lines before that one would help me to debug the issue (you can get those with `journalctl -u mariadb.service`, but out of the top of my head, it looks like you might have corrupted data on that node. In that case it could be worth removing the entire contents of the MariaDB datadir (`rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/*`, or wherever your datadir is located) and let Galera resync that node with fresh data through a SST.